# Error in starting Jboss 6.2 EAP

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x

I am trying to deploy my war in Jboss 6.2 but getting below exception while starting the Jboss. Please help me to resolve this issue:

15:33:42,714 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/authService]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) JBWEB000287: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This parser does not support specification "null" version "null"
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setSchema(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at __redirected.__DocumentBuilderFactory.setSchema(__DocumentBuilderFactory.java:194) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.opensaml.xml.parse.BasicParserPool.initializePool(BasicParserPool.java:510) [xmltooling-1.3.2.jar:]
    at org.opensaml.xml.parse.BasicParserPool.(BasicParserPool.java:138) [xmltooling-1.3.2.jar:]
    at org.opensaml.xml.XMLConfigurator.(XMLConfigurator.java:87) [xmltooling-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.opensaml.xml.XMLConfigurator.(XMLConfigurator.java:73) [xmltooling-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.opensaml.DefaultBootstrap.initializeXMLTooling(DefaultBootstrap.java:195) [opensaml-2.5.3.jar:1.0.0.RC2]
    at org.opensaml.DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap(DefaultBootstrap.java:91) [opensaml-2.5.3.jar:1.0.0.RC2]
    at org.opensaml.PaosBootstrap.bootstrap(PaosBootstrap.java:27) [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.0.RC2.jar:1.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLBootstrap.postProcessBeanFactory(SAMLBootstrap.java:42) [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.0.RC2.jar:1.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694) [spring-context-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:684) [spring-context-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461) [spring-context-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410) [spring-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have different versions of spring jar in your WEB-INF/lib or in your jboss lib, can cause the  said issue. Trying removing those.